# Why is my box div sitting behind the two elements that should be above it?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm a web design newbie trying to work out a problem with my css and/or html. My page has two grid50 divs that should above a div that is a colored box. However, the box sits behind the other sections(though the box content is pushed down).

My html:

```
<div>
<div class="grid-50 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100 first-column">
   <?php $description = get_field('country_description', $term); 
    echo "<p>" . $description . "</p>";
     ?>
 </div>
 <div class="grid-50 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100 second-column">

  <?php $description = get_field('country_description', $term);
  $map = get_field('country_map', $term);
  echo do_shortcode( ' '. $map .' ' ); 
    ?>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="infobox">
    <?php 
    $when = get_field('info_box_when', $term);
     $where = get_field('info_box_where', $term);
     $moment = get_field('info_box_moment', $term);
     $fact = get_field('info_box_fact', $term);
    $description = get_field('info_box', $term); 
    echo '<h6>' . 'When we visited:   ' . '</h6>' . '<p>' . $when . '</p>' . '<br>' .
        '<h6>' . 'Major stops:   ' . '</h6>' . '<p>' . $where . '</p>' . '<br>' .
        '<h6>' . 'Memorable moment:   ' . '</h6>' . '<p>' . $moment . '</p>' . '<br>' .
        '<h6>' . 'Did you know?   ' . '</h6>' . '<p>' . $fact . '</p>';
                    ?>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.infobox {
    background-color: #bf593a;
    color: white;
    padding: 5%;
    border-radius: 10px ;
    margin-left:6%;
    margin-right: 6%;
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;;
}
```

Here's the result:
https://theslowroad.org/category/destinations/asia/laos/

The orange box *should* be below the text and map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the text and map above the orange block is floated, which means you need to clear it. Add `clear: both;` to the rules for your orange (`.infobox`) box.